# Stubbing a class within a namespace

Tags: rspec

I have the following controller spec that works just fine right now:

```
# This top part is a hack
module MyModule
  class MyOAuthClient < OAuthClient
    def token_is_valid?(options)
      true
    end
  end 
end

# Here's the actual spec
describe MyModule::OAuthController do
  describe "GET callback" do
    it "works fine when token is valid" do
      post :callback, use_route: :my_module
      expect(response.code).to eq("200")
    end 
  end 
end
```

What I want to do is replace the monkey patch in my spec with a stub. How do I do this?

The [rspec-mocks docs](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks) show examples for stubbing classes that aren't under namespaces, but it doesn't seem that you can just apply those examples to namespaced classes and have it work.

I've tried certain things already but I don't want to bias people's answers with my incorrect guesses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was after `any_instance`:

```
MyModule::OAuthClient.any_instance.stub(:token_is_valid?) { true }
```